# If $A^2$ and $B^2$ are similar matrices, do $A$ and $B$ have to be similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the converse is true; that is, if A and B are similar matrices, then $A^2$ and $B^2$ are similar . However, I'm not sure about the reverse.

Comment: Consider $1\times 1$ matrices $A = [1]$ and $B = [-1]$ :)

Answer (score 45):

No: consider
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: To the downvoter: what's wrong or unclear here?

Comment: Well you used one more dimension than you needed to, but I agree that's not good cause for a downvote...

Comment: @R.. Of course dimension one would suffice, but I felt it wouldn't be a clear example to the OP.

Answer (score 15):

A little more dramatic, should you want another example:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad
B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$